# Scrolling left/right to new pages

Tags: java, android, user-interface, tabs, scroll

I am creating an application which displays several "pages" of content. Typically this is representative as tabs on a desktop based application.

On android, I want to be able to flick between the tabs of information, using there finger anywhere on the screen. The content of these tabs will just be XML views, or programmatically created views.

Looking at Applications on android, there are several applications that do this. Google Play, Gmail, Beautiful Widgets, BBC News, Contacts, Engadget.

I've looked for several terms, mostly scrollable tabs but haven't found anything that is similar to the above applications. I'm looking at TabHost, TabWidget and ViewPaper at the moment, but not sure if these do what I'm looking for.

Can anyone tell me which control can be used in android to get the functionality. Out of the apps listed I'm looking to have it styled more like the Google Play store, with the name of the tab at the top, and the names of the nearby tabs to the left and right if applicable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for [this](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator). It's compatible with ViewPager, the v4 compatibility library, and ActionBarSherlock.

Comment: Looks just liek the thing I needed. I did come across it but discounted it for some reason. I've compiled the code and "Titles" is the one I wanted. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

There is an example on the android blog for this, used on google play app.

[Horizontal View Swiping with ViewPager](http://android-developers.blogspot.com.br/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html)